# Tweepy get_followed_lists not returning results

Tags: python, tweepy

Has anyone got a working example of how to use Tweepy, Twiter API v2 to bring back a list of people that a user follows? Here is my attempt but I keep getting empty results  back:

```
import tweepy
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd
import time
from datetime import date
from datetime import datetime 
        
token='<insert token>'
client = tweepy.Client(bearer_token=token,wait_on_rate_limit=True)
        
startHandle = "IOHK_Charles"
usr = client.get_user(username=startHandle,user_fields='public_metrics')
d=client.get_followed_lists(usr.data.id)
```

Comment: Did you get any result from `client.get_user`?

Comment: Ok I figured it out. Should have been using `get_users_following` instead of `get_followed_lists`. Hope that helps someone else!

Answer (score 1):

Ok I figured it out. Should have been using `get_users_following` instead of `get_followed_lists`. Hope that helps someone else!